# Embeding EasyVideoPlayer Code into Wordpress Theme - Video not showing

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, video, embed

I'm attempting to place some embed code into a Premium WordPress Theme. 
NOTE: I'm not great when it comes to php.

The embed code is produced by a video player called EasyVideoPlayer. (Basically it allows me to use Amazon S3 and gives me feedback on when people stop watching the video.)

This is the embed code I have:

`<div id="evp-3f0d657d2345b5ea751153sc3a4b2c0e-wrap" class="evp-video-wrap"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mysite.co.uk/evp/framework.php?div_id=evp-3f0d657d4255b2ea9817650c3a3b2c0e&id=ZXh0cmEtbW9uZXktZnJvbS1ob21lLTEubW92&v=1275160528"></script><script type="text/javascript">_evpInit('ZXh0cmEtbW9uZXktZnJvbS1ob21lLTEubW92');</script>`

I've opened the index.php wordpress file and placed this video embed code in between the  that represents the area of the website I want it to show up. However the video is not showing.

If we place both the theme and video player aside, would you expect the php code to accept what I've done or is this not the way to go about adding this embed code?

NOTE:I've contacted both the Wordpress Premium Theme support at Woothemes.com and the video players support for EasyVideoPlayer.com However both tend to stop at the point that another paid product is involved! Grrreat.

website is www.extramoneyfromhome.co.uk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a [WordPress plugin for EasyVideoPlayer](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easyvideoplayer/), which solves this issue. It's also a heck of a lot nicer working with the visual editor instead of hard-coding the video into the template.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the code all in one block - at present the Script is in the header, rather than below the DIV tag.

This is just an idea to rule out a simple problem.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: Thanks I've sorted this now. In the end it was a security setting with the EasyVideoPlayer that restricted the video to the domain. I chose this but for some reason it stripped the www. from the domain. I removed this and now it is working o.k.